# thrift javascript client python server

Tags: javascript, python, json, thrift

In my python client I can get the answer for 1+1 .but when I use a javascript client I can't get a output.How should I call the add() method in python server using javascript. helloworld.thrift ,server.py and test.html javascript client files are mentioned below.how should I pass json object to python server and get the output corresponding to the add() method? .Here I pass the "work" json object.If it is wrong how should I call add() function in python and get the result for two integer values in correct way.
Thank You.

**helloworld.thrift**`

```
service HelloWorld{
string ping(),
i32 add(1:i32 num1,2:i32 num2)}`
```

**server.py**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys
sys.path.append('./gen-py')

from helloworld import HelloWorld
from helloworld.ttypes import *

from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.server import TServer

class HelloWorldHandler:
  def ping(self):
    return "pong"

  def add(self, n1, n2):
  #print('add(%d,%d)' % (n1, n2))
   return n1 + n2

handler = HelloWorldHandler()
processor = HelloWorld.Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port = 9090)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

server = TServer.TSimpleServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

print "Starting thrift server in python..."
server.serve()
print "done!"
```

**test.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head> 
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
         <title>Using Javascript Prompt and Alert for test</title>




              <script src="thrift-0.9.3/lib/js/src/thrift.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
              <script src="gen-js/HelloWorld.js"        type="text/javascript"></script>
              <script src="gen-js/helloworld_types.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 


                 var name;
                 name=window.prompt("please enter the variable","user");

                 document.writeln("<h1>Hello," + name + "    welcome to javascript and thrift</h1>");




        function addition() {
             var transport = new Thrift.Transport("http://localhost:9090");
             var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
             var client    = new HelloWorldClient(protocol);

             var work = new object();
             work.num1 = window.prompt("please enter the number 1","num1");
             work.num2 = window.prompt("please enter the number 2","num2");
             var result;



             result = client.add(1, work);
             document.writeln(result);
    }






      </script>
   </head>


   <body>
        <h1>Thrift javascript binding</h1>

        <a href="javascript:addition()">Hello</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check your code against the [Thrift tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/)? **If not, please have a look**. It's pretty much the same use case (if we want to call it that way) as you have here, so you should be able to get it working using the tutorial as a blueprint.

Comment: yes.I have read the tutorial.thrift in official document and I wrote this code with the help of that document.But I am unable to print the result of the 1+1 on the test.html. But when I use the python client I could do that.How should I call  def add(self,n1,n2) method and get the output.Thank You.

Comment: Does the original tutorial work? If it does, compare it against your code.